# Semantically mark up a chat

Tags: html, chat, semantic-markup

I'm beginner in HTML and I'm looking for a **semantically correct way** to mark up the author's nickname, author's picture and his message in a chat.

The chat has this shape:

[image]

Comment: Well, you can always try mine: [martinandersson.com/livechat](http://www.martinandersson.com/livechat).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WHATWG's living standard says:](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#conversations)

> This specification does not define a specific element for marking up
>   conversations, meeting minutes, chat transcripts, dialogues in
>   screenplays, instant message logs, and other situations where
>   different players take turns in discourse.
>
> Instead, authors are encouraged to mark up conversations using p
>   elements and punctuation. Authors who need to mark the speaker for
>   styling purposes are encouraged to use span or b. Paragraphs with
>   their text wrapped in the i element can be used for marking up stage
>   directions.

which, ugh, well, but there you go. You could see if there's a suitable [microdata format](http://microformats.org/) and [ARIA](http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/aria.php) annotations, though.